# Construction JSON value dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, json

My below code works fine if I repace my "temp" with any other hard-coded string value. But I am not sure How can I pass the temp value each time in the JSON I am creating. How can I fix this?
I need to have my json something like `{"device1": 24, "device2": 25, "device3": 26}`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
            {
                string temp = (i + 23).ToString();
                dynamic foo = JObject.FromObject(new { Hello = "{ \"device\" : temp }" });
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: i am passing the events in an eventhub and there I am trying to do some filtering

Comment: Why are you dynamically constructing the json and why are you using dynamic? It isn't clear what the input is or what you expect the output to be, and, as a result it is isn't clear why you need this type of approach in the first place.

Comment: its just a sample code i took from one of MS docs page, the input here is constructed that is the json value i mentioned in question, this input is then send as an event to event hub. I can hardcode the whole json and send it as event but I would like to do this way so that I get flexibility to send n number of events.

Comment: *use a Dictionary*. What you are showing as a sample is a `Dictionary<string,int>` - just build that and let the serializer do its job. Building JSON as strings is almost always the wrong solution.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

if you want to use JObject

```
    var numOfEvents = 3;
    JObject jo = new JObject();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
        jo.Add("device" + i.ToString(), i + 23);

    JObject jsonObject = new JObject();
    jsonObject["Hello"] = jo;
```

result

```
{ "Hello": {"device1" : 24,"device2" : 25,"device3" : 26}}
```

Some people are getting furious when they see a string builder, although it is not so heavy as a serializer with libraries. So if you want to put into json only several items,  you can just use a string. Create a json string manually  is very handy if  for some reasons you don't wont to install a a heavy weight json serializer libraries since you just need to create a short string.

```
    numOfEvents = 2;
    var json = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
    {
        string temp = (i + 23).ToString();
        json += $",\"device{i}\" : {temp}";
    }
    json = "{ \"Hello\": {" + json.Substring(1) + "}}";
```

but in some casses when you need a lot of items (for testing for example) it is better to use a string builder

```
    var numOfEvents = 3;
    StringBuilder sb= new ();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
    {
        string temp = (i + 23).ToString();
         sb.Append( $",\"device{i}\" : {temp}");
    }
    
    var json="{ \"Hello\": {"+ sb.ToString().Substring(1)+ "}}";
    
    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

result

```
{ "Hello" : { "device1" : 24,"device2" : 25,"device3" : 26 }
```

Comment: I would strongly advise *against* using a `StringBuilder` like this to create JSON. Sure, if you're only using numeric values it may well be fine - but as soon as someone tries to use the same code for string values including backslashes etc, you'll end up with invalid JSON. Far better to use second approach, and let Json.NET (or System.Text.Json) handle the actual JSON part.

Comment: "As I understand it is just a demo." I see no evidence of that in the question... and even so, you've given this as a Stack Overflow answer that could well be copied by anyone, with *no warning whatsoever* that creating the JSON manually is error-prone... indeed, you've even claimed it's "better" without any justification or caveats. Yes, there are times when creating the JSON manually is more appropriate - but I'd suggest they're very rare, and it should *only* be done after due consideration of the risks of ending up with incorrect JSON - none of which you've explained here.

Comment: To put it another way: would you feel no concerns about an answer that created SQL queries dynamically using a `StringBuilder` instead of using a parameterized query, and claimed this was a "better" approach? It's much the same.

Comment: "I would use string builder if I need a large quantiy iterations" - by default? Without even performing any performance testing to check whether any performance benefit is actually worth the additional scrutiny required to ensure correctness? That doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: "Create a json string manually is very handy if for some reasons you don't wont to install a a heavy weight json serializer libraries since you just need to create a short string." - and if you don't care about correctness, or *assume* that just because you're only using numeric values right now, that that will be the case in the future...