# Returning array from methods C#

Tags: c#, methods, reference, heap-memory, pass-by-reference

I have been wondering, why isn't my method, modifying the array, when I used it as a parameter and made it equal to another array with different values, inside the method?
Am I just changing the reference address?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] array = { "yes", "no", "maybe" };
        TestO(array); // Still "yes", "no", "maybe"
    }

    static void TestO(string[] array)
    {
        string[] secondArray = new string[array.Length]; 
        secondArray[0] = "1";
        secondArray[1] = "2";
        secondArray[2] = "3";
        array = secondArray; 
    }
```

My guess: I did not modify the array inside the Main(), because when doing `array = secondArray;` in the `Test0()` method,
I just changed the reference address of `array` to `secondArray`.

If my guess is not right, my question is, why exactly is it not getting modified?

(I know that I can just modify `Test0()` to a `string[]` return method and return the modified `secondArray` and pass it on to the `array` in `Main()`)

Another questions is:
If I use the `string[]` return method, and declare the following:

```
        static void Main()
    {
        string[] array = { "yes", "no", "maybe" };
        array = TestO(array); 
    }

    static string[] TestO(string[] methodArray)
    {
        string[] secondArray = new string[methodArray.Length];
        secondArray[0] = "1";
        secondArray[1] = "2";
        secondArray[2] = "3";
        return secondArray; 
    }
```

`array = TestO(array);` am I just passing the reference address of the `secondArray[]` to `array[]` or am I passing only the values of it? (Most probably it will be the reference address, but I wanted to be sure if mistaken)

Comment: For the first question - array is a reference type and so when the function `Test0` is called it calls a copy constructor of the array's reference so basically you assign the modified array to local copy of the reference, thus not affecting it outside the function scope.

Comment: For the second question - because `secondArray` is a reference type - the reference is passed, not the values themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just changed the reference address of array to secondArray. If my guess is not right, my question is, why exactly is it not getting modified?

I think you're leaning towards appreciating that there are two references to one data in memory (there are not two data); you have a variable `array` that points to data. You call a method and another, copy reference is established to the same data. You made a new object, then you pointed the copied reference at the new object, leaving the original reference pointing to the original data, then you threw the copy reference and the new data away.. You're back to the exact same situation you started with.

Pictorially, line by line, it might look like (I renamed your method argument to `arrayX` so the difference is obvious):

[image]

If you decorate the argument with `ref` and call it with `ref` there is no copy, so the called method can modify the original reference and point it somewhere else:

[image]

Note that in *either* of these cases it's perfectly possible to modify the *contents* of the array. Doing:

```
arrayX[0] = "New data";
```

..would take effect in *either* case and printing `array[0]` would show "New data". When modifying the data at the end of the arrow it matters not whether the starting point is an original reference or a copy. This is *purely* about whether the method has the power to point the original reference passed to it, to a different object or not

Generally we *don't* do it. We adopt the style of your second code block - to return the data. It may help to see it as rude - imagine your friend says he'll look after your plant while you're on holiday; you give your keys to your friend. He swaps your plant for a different one that he likes better; you're upset because you had that plant for ten years..

There are very few reasons to use `ref`, or the related "power to overwite your reference" - `out`. Don't use it for "I wanted to return multiple things from my method" - in an OO world we can always return one thing that represents two items of data. We don't need to "return two things"; we can return one thing with two things inside it...

```
//don't:
void GetPerson(ref string name, ref int age)

//consider a class:
Person GetPerson()
  return new Person(){ Name = ..., Age = ...}

//or a Tuple
(string Name, int Age) GetPerson
```

Let the calling method choose whether its own variable should be overwritten, rather than having some "third party" pull that rug from under its feet

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an array to a method

```
static void Test0(string[] array)
{
```

You are passing a *reference* to that array.  That reference is effectively *immutable* (you're getting a copy of the reference, not the original one), so you can't change the parameter reference and expect it to affect the code outside of the Test method.

While you can do this to get the behavior you want:

```
static void Test0(ref string[] array)
{
```

it's not considered good C# style.  Strings are themselves immutable; the "correct" style is to return them from the method.  This is also true of string arrays.

The only thing you would be saving by using this technique is an extra reference and a `return` statement, since you're still creating new strings and a new array anyway.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to return anything , just use a ref

```
static void Test( ref string[] array)
    {
        string[] secondArray = new string[array.Length]; 
        secondArray[0] = "1";
        secondArray[1] = "2";
        secondArray[2] = "3";
        array = secondArray; 
    }
```

Comment: Nooo.... Don't encourage it.

Comment: @CaiusJard ok you are right, I don' t want to make waves here any more.  People are too serious here, don' t  appreciate any joke

Comment: This was a joke answer?

Comment: Mmm.. I personally feel you cannot joke with someone's education.. Not wishing to come across as overly serious, but the general ambience in SO is intended to err more towards professional than joking

Comment: @RobertHarvey not this one

Comment: @CaiusJard I hate when somebody thinks that there is only one right answer. There is no such a thing.  I like to have the several alternatives. Doesn't matter if they look akward.  But here not everybody understands it

Comment: I completely agree, and I'm definitely not saying "there is only one right answer", but it's vital that answers wishing to convey that aren't just "here's a fish you wanted" but instead "here's fish A and I caught it like.. becuase... And also here is fish B which will also meet your needs because ... and I caught it like ...". Had your answer included more words of explanation than code I would have been much less likely to speak up and say "hang on"..

Comment: There are different kinds of questions here, but lets divvy them broadly into newbies looking for help with really basic stuff that's hard to google, an dmore experienced sorts looking for really precise, targeted advice for a highly specific problem that only a few SME would be able to answer well. It's actually the *latter* questions where you can get away with a code-only with minimal explanation, because the ability to understand the entire context, the whys and wherefores is already there in the OP.In the really basic questions;they are the people who benefit most from extra explanation

Comment: @CaiusJard string[] Test( ref string[] array) is good for lambda style, like this Tect(array).ContinueToDo().  But  unfortunately here it will be immediately downvoted

Comment: I'm not certain I agree - I might have missed the point but if you were to take a look at the [source code of Enumerable.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs) - basically the embodiment of method syntax LINQ and fluent style data manipulation, you can't find a single `ref` method (other than a couple of times where they call Array.Resize()). I think if they were `ref`/working in a "reffy" style, there would be bizarre side effects all over the place and it would make keeping track of how your data was being manipulated very hard..

Comment: @CaiusJard I am not taking about this case only, in this case maybe more often it could be used as Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",", Test(ref array)));  .My point is that should be several versions, it could be usefull in some casses. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71186671/11392290 . I am not going to delete it, people should know what kind of users are here. I don't see any wrong with this answer, just two possible ways to create json. I think you remember several questions, when people asked how to create  a simple json without json library.They didn' t want  make it very heavy.

Comment: @CaiusJard  Sorry, I didn' t have room to show you Enumerable example var list=Test(ref array).Where(x => x!="2" ).ToList();

Comment: Why is the `ref` mandatory/helpful there though? It's what I'm struggling with, mentally. C# returns the result of an assignment so if my method X wanted its `array` variable replaced and also call Where on it, I can make `Test` take and return an array and call it like `var list = (array = Test(array)).Where(...)` - this way it is the calling method that keeps control of whether its array variable is overwritten when it didn't want it to be. The `array = Test(array)` calls Test, supplying `array`, Test returns a new whatever, and then the new watever is assigned to `array` and the return..

Comment: ..value resulting from the assignment is the new array, with then has its Where called, which operates in the same way - it returns a new thing, not overwriting the thing it is given